# what is the difference betweeen Tcp protocol and Remote Procedure Call?

Tags: java, tcp, rpc, gprs

can anyone please explain which protocol is more scalable and what the difference is between

1. TCP (TRANSMISSION CONTROL PROTOCOL),and
2. RPC(REMOTE PROCEDURE CALL).

Answer (score 14):

RPC - **Remote Procedure Call** basically is a form of inter-process communication that allows one program to directly call procedures in another program either on the same machine or another machine on the network.

For more details see the wikipedia article: [Remote procedure call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call)

RPC runs on top of (uses) TCP. TCP allows computers to send arbitrary length data to each other with guaranteed delivery.  RPC operates at the same level as POP, SMTP, and other protocols.  Those protocols also run on top of TCP.

TCP is a lower level protocol.  Since RPC runs on top of TCP your question about scalability is not relevant.

Comment: Just to be clear, RPC may run on TCP or also may run on top of other protocols. The difference is in the layer of the protocol. The OSI 7 layer architecture is good for this. RPC is layer 7 (application) and TCP is a transport at layer 4.

Comment: Quite true @FrancisUpton. I was going to mention that, but decided that he probably doesn't know what OSI layer's are so kept it simple.

Comment: No one knows what OSI layers are except us ancients. :)